# Random characters coming in on CSS ::after pseudo element

Tags: css

On occasion, it appears that pseudo elements display seemingly random content in place of ISO content used to display various icons.

In the screenshot, there initially was an angle quotation mark using:

```
content:'\00bb ';
```

Somehow, the content got changed to:

```
content: 'â–¼ ';
```

This happens pretty often with our site builds, but usually the randomly generated code is much longer and uglier.

Initially this was thought to be the result of using symbols directly in the CSS like the following:

```
content: '» '
```

This, when it broke as described above, would generate much more random and ugly looking character strings.

We've long since stopped using symbols directly in the CSS and switched to strictly using ISO content for simple symbols which is the correct way to do it, but we are still getting errors.

The files are saved in a CMS and the CMS is built using Smarty/PHP.

I've not been able to find other examples of this happening when searching online and I'm wondering if it has to do with the way CMS is built. That somehow the CMS is stripping out the ISO content when parsing the files and the other elements put in it's place.

When developing the sites, we typically use Chrome dev tools to create the CSS and copy and paste the CSS into into the CMS CSS file. Not sure how or when the content gets messed up, and it doesn't happen all the time. It's very unpredictable.

Any help would be appreciated.

[screenshot with odd characters coming in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPcKj.jpg)

[pseudo element working as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18iUI.jpg)

Comment: Did you tried using `00BB` (uppercase letters)? Because it's [referenced like this](http://graphemica.com/%C2%BB) in Unicode.

Comment: What does "the content got changed" mean? Do you mean the css file was magically changed?

Comment: Yes. See screenshots. ISO content was coming in, then random characters inexplicably start displaying. Don't know what triggers this. Maybe CMS parsing the the CSS file and messing it up somehow? No idea..

Comment: Kovah - case should not matter. My go to resource for getting ISO equivalents for symbols is - https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/glyphs/ - they don't use uppercase letters.

Answer (score 0):

Are you editing the css in the same encoding than your index file ?
(make sure to use utf-8 or any other encoding with both your css and your html files)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you provide the charset `<meta>` tag:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Since you're using it in a webpage try using the HTML encoding: `&#xbb;`. Example:

```html
<h1>&#xbb; Shipping</h1>
```

Comment: The content in that part of the CMS is not accessible and content cannot be added directly, hence the use of ::pseudo content.